# Grouping items in Java

Tags: java

I know that in java I can group items like:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(1,2,3,3,4,2,2).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                   Collectors.counting())));
```

that would return:

> {1=1, 2=3, 3=2, 4=1}

However I have the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    final int NO_OF_STUDENTS = 10000;
    Student[] students = createStudents(NO_OF_STUDENTS);
}
```

Here I have an students array which contains many Student object, each Student has the .getGrade() method.

I'm trying to do something like:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(students.getGrade()).stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                   Collectors.counting())));
```

I know that the students array itself does not have the `.getGrade()` method, but its elements do. What I want is that I can pass the grade of all the students from the `students` array to the `Arrays.asList()` method, I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the [map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method for this?

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(students)
        .map(Student::getGrade)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting())));
```

Here I'm mapping the students stream to a stream of grades and then grouping them.

I think that is good to point out that you don't need to use [Arrays.asList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) for this. You can create a Stream of your students array directly with [Arrays.stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-T:A-).

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I prefer to use a traditional loop over streams for producing maps. With the improvements made to the `Map` interface in Java 8, this can be done particularly cleanly.

```
Map<Integer, Integer> gradeCounts = new TreeMap<>();
for (Student student : students)
    gradeCounts.merge(student.getGrade(), 1, Integer::sum);
```

Comment: Why use `TreeMap`?

Comment: I answered this question a few days ago now so I'm not sure of my reasoning, but I guess it was that grades have a natural order so it makes sense to use an ordered map.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the streams `mapToInt()` method:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(students).stream()
    .mapToInt(student -> student.getGrade())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                   Collectors.counting())));
```

> You can't use a collector on an IntStream. – shmosel

then lets do a "normal" map:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(students).stream()
    .map(student -> student.getGrade())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                   Collectors.counting())));
```

Comment: Beat me to it by 16 seconds ;)

Comment: including verification of API... ;o)

Comment: You can't use a collector on an IntStream.

Comment: Fair point @shmosel . And Timothy I think you got one parenthesis too much after students :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably

```
System.out.println(
  Arrays.asList(students)
  .stream()
  .map(s -> s.getGrade())
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
);
```

?

The idea being that you first create a stream of your `Student`, then create another Stream by `map`ing each student to their grade. That will give you a `Stream<Integer>` which you can collect as usual.

[Link to docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-)

Comment: *That will give you an `IntStream` which you can then collect as usual.* No you can't. You need to use a regular stream.

Comment: Also, you can just use `Arrays.stream()`.

Comment: Also you can use `Student::getGrade` for the mapping function.

Comment: Thanks for the first hint; Corrected. I am still getting used to the Stream API and am thnkful for any experience I can get.
Yes I could use it but I mostly stick to the code given in the question.
And yes I could use method reference but I rather stick to lambdas based on personal preference @shmosel Thanks for your input!

Comment: Why use `.mapToInt(...).boxed()` when you can just use `.map()`?

Comment: Because I am still getting used to it as I said. I don't always know everything. Answering provides me with another way to learn. Thanks for the improvement!